# How to detect the colors of an image that is in a folder in internal storage with OpenCV and Android Studio?

Tags: android, opencv

I don't know much about Android Studio and I have to make the detection of the colors of an image. I'm using OpenCV and I found some code that does it but it only detects the colors of images that are at the root of internal storage, and I want to do that but with images that are at a folder called "Pictures".

This is the part of the code that does that:

```
Mat img = imread(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "im.jpg");

Mat oImg = detectColor(img);
```

I tried adding the full path of the image but when I did that the app did not work:

```
Mat img = imread(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/im.jpg");

Mat oImg = detectColor(img);
```

This is all the MainActivity.java, i haven't added the part to take and save the picture.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISOS = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
private Toast toast;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity" ;
ImageView imgView;
Button processBtn;
TextView txtResult;

// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

private BaseLoaderCallback _baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    }
};

//to check whether opencv is loaded successfully or not.
static {
    if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV loaded successfully");
    }else {
        Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV not loaded");

    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    permisos();
    processBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.processImgBtn);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);


    processBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            processImage();
        }
    });
}



private void processImage(){

    //reading input image from internal storage.
    /*Se lee la imagen que quieres, pero desde el almacenamiento interno de tu celular, debes poner la imagen
    "colores.jpg" en el directorio raíz del almacenamiento interno de tu celular, en este caso estará leyendo
     todo el tiempo "colores.jpg" y hará lo que OPENCV quiera hacer con la imagen */
    Mat img = imread(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ storage / emulated / 0 / Pictures / im.jpg");
    Mat oImg = detectColor(img);

    // converting image from Mat to bitmap to display in ImageView:
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(oImg.cols(), oImg.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(oImg,bm);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bm);
}


Mat detectColor(Mat srcImg) {
    Mat blurImg = new Mat();
    Mat hsvImage = new Mat();
    Mat color_range_red = new Mat();
    Mat color_range_green = new Mat();
    Mat color_range = new Mat();

    //bluring image to filter small noises.
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(srcImg, blurImg, new Size(5,5),0);

    //converting blured image from BGR to HSV
    Imgproc.cvtColor(blurImg, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    //filtering red and green pixels based on given opencv HSV color range
    Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(0,50,50), new Scalar(5,255,255), color_range_red);
    Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(40,50,50), new Scalar(50,255,255), color_range_green);

    //applying bitwise or to detect both red and green color.
    Core.bitwise_or(color_range_red,color_range_green,color_range);

    return color_range;


}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults){
    String mensaje = "";
    if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mensaje = "Permiso Concedido";
    }else{
        mensaje = "Permiso no concedido";
    }
    toast = Toast.makeText(this, mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
private void permisos(){
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if(permissionCheck!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){ //No tiene el permiso
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    PERMISOS,
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }
}





@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        //try to load again
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, _baseLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        _baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is too broad question. What you have tried so far, what you did? What is the exact issue?

Comment: ok, i have to do an app where i can take a picture and save it in the phone, and them i have to detect the color red of the picture with opencv. i tried to save the picture in the internal storage because i could only do the detection with pictures that weren´t inside a folder but i couldn't. So i want to know if there is a code or option to do the detection of a picture that is inside a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Right folder for the Pictures you can take with next part.

```
final File path = Environment
              .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
final File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");
```

Comment: Thank u so much, i couldn't fix my problem with the detection but i used your solution to save the pictures in the roof of internal storage

Comment: @JOSUEYAIRSOSAOCHOA Just be clear in question and keep it simple. Usually people will not write application for you. But help you to resolve a specific issue.